# 2D Sprite components causing text (TextMeshPro) components to be hidden in Unity

Tags: unity

Edit: Depending on where my game character is located in the map, some text (TextMeshPro) components get hidden/turn invisible.

I have tried to figure out what is causing this. With the help of a comment on this post I found out that the problem is located at the 2D Sprite components (background) of each chatbubble. Once I turn these 2D Sprite components off, the text is always visible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

On these screenshots you can see that the 2D Sprite components (background) get sorted in front of the text components depending on where (i assume) my camera or player is located on the map.

Comment: Your last screenshot still has a nullpointer error. Since script execution gets halted after an error for that script, make sure your game first does not throw those. It might be related, it might not be. But from just what its shown, we cant say for sure. And are all your canvas of type overlay?

Comment: @Zibelas The Nullpointer error has been fixed. Also, all the canvas are of type overlay indeed.

Comment: Is it possible the chat bubble is somehow getting sorted in front of the text? Have you tried disabling the Image component on the chat bubble to see if the text is visible behind it?

Comment: What seems odd to me, your answer container is NOT part of any of your canvas components. To render them correctly, they should be in one.

Comment: @Kevin I'm afraid that's exactly what is happening. I just tested it. Good thing now i know where the problem is at. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this question:

1. Set the 'Order in Layer' of each 2D sprite component (the background of each chatbubble) to 0
2. In the inspector window of a text component, search for 'Extra Settings'
3. Set the 'Order in Layer' of each text component to 10